# print horizontal line in Makefile output

Tags: makefile, output, printf

looking for a little Makefile candy; nothing mission critical. I have this Makefile output:

```
$ make
all              The Whole Enchilada
target01         Descript1
target02         Descript2
target03         Descript3
target04         Descript4
```

For some reason I can't seem to make it print out a horizontal line in the output; looking for this:

```
$ make
all              The Whole Enchilada
target01         Descript1
target02         Descript2
------------------------------------------------ make all ends here
target03         Descript3
target04         Descript4
```

Just a simple separator with a right-justified message.

I should share, this is the end of my Makefile, it prints all targets:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#    
#------------------------   MANAGERIAL OVERHEAD   ----------------------------# 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
print-%  : ## Print any variable from the Makefile (e.g. make print-VARIABLE);  
        @echo $* = $($*)                                                        
                                                                                
.PHONY: help                                                                    
                                                                                
help:                                                                           
        @grep -E '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-16s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
                                                                                
.DEFAULT_GOAL := help
```

Extra bonus points if you can help me understand it in a one-liner printf statement; printf doesn't fit very well in my head for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide your current `Makefile`, but this does not look very complicated:

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
        @printf "all\t\tThe Whole Enchilada\n"
        @printf "target01\tDescript1\n"
        @printf "target02\tDescript2\n"
        @printf -- "------------------------------------------------ make all ends here\n"
        @printf "target03\tDescript3\n"
        @printf "target04\tDescript4\n"


$ make
all             The Whole Enchilada
target01        Descript1
target02        Descript2
------------------------------------------------ make all ends here
target03        Descript3
target04        Descript4
```

The only thing is that you need to use `--` in `printf` call to explicitly state that the options part is finished and all the rest are positional arguments, otherwise `printf` will try to interpret your horizontal line as an option.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the `help:` target; sorry, I wasn't clear about that. Is there a way to get it to print that doesn't require it to be in the `all:` target?

Comment: Can you then also explain when do you want this separator printed? It looks like `help` target just prints out all the targets with their descriptions, but it's not clear when should the separator be printed.

Comment: sticking with the example above, right after `^target02.*$` - I think would be the way to express that.